# How to detect if the backbone.js model is cleared

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, underscore.js

js I wonder on how to detect if the model is cleared or empty?

if I set the model

```
model.set({name:'this is a test', id:1});
```

and clear it

```
model.clear();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can test for this by doing the following:

```
if ($.isEmptyObject(model.attributes)) {
    // model is cleared or empty
}
```

Note that you cannot rely on the `model.isNew()` function as it does not verify whether the model has had **all** of its attributes removed.

You can see a [working fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/m2FaL/3/).

Comment: Why the downvote? This works. You can even look at the linked fiddle to see it in action.

Comment: hahaha! thanks for this! i just tried also this _.isEmpty(this.model.attributes)

Comment: @dcarson -1 was for untested broken code example. +1 for fixing it.

Comment: Thanks jgb. Just returned the nice gesture